# Как получить имена всех дочерних объектов в Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: c#, unity3d, firebase

Как получить имена всех дочерних объектов в Firebase Realtime Database? Мне нужно получить массив string с именами всех дочерних объектов из "Servers". Долго голову ломаю, не знаю что делать.